# Get Data from Text File to Multidimensional Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array, text-files

I have a little bit of an issue with a JavaScript function that needs to read data from a TextFile (something JS is already limited with) and then process tha TextFile data into a MultiDimensional Array (another thing that JS doesn't nativelly suport).

With that in mind, I have a text file in this format:

```
1, Name, Data, Serial
2, Name, Data, Serial
3, Name, Data, Serial
```

And so on.

So, the objective is to get that same data and put it, like that, into an array.

I suppose that, from what I've been reading, I need an Array of an Array, segmenting the first one by lines [/n] and the second one by commas [,]. However, given the "by-default" limitations, I'm very confused at this point. I do suppose I need jQuery, however.

I tried this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in array) {
  var array = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split(",");
  for(f in array) {

  }
}
```

With little success, because then I don't really know how to store it, the objective being a Multidimensional Array that Replicates the Format of the text file, so latter it could be used to search by index or instance following an user input to get results.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: First of all, javascript does have native 2D arrays.  Second, Node's FS module is great at reading text files line-by-line.  There are probably tons of tutorials out there for it.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems like you are trying to read in a CSV file.  If that is indeed the case I recommend node-csv:

http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/

https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

Answer (score 0):

This helped me reading file to JavaScript, however this example converts retrieved data to JSON. Just looking at the format of your text file, I would assume a JSON string or Javascript object would work with your data.

[Example convert to JSON](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7027/converting-input-from-a-filereader-to-json-and-outputting-it-again)

With JSON and JS objects, instead of referencing a array indexes eg. array[i][x]. you would replace [x] with .propertyName

```
 data = {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Fred"
 };
 //access data like this
 data[i].name      //will return "Fred" as i =0
```

to create JS object, just initialize array properties without the ""(quotation marks). accessing JS and JSON properties are done in the same way, main advantage over a multidimensional array is that you can reference an actual property name, as opposed to indexes.